# How do I exclude dates from angular material datepicker?

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material

I am using Angular Material and I have a dynamic array of dates that I wish to exclude from my datepicker. In addition I am also trying to exclude Saturdays. How can I return multiple dates with my matDatepickerFilter?
Keep in mind that I cant hardcode each item of the array individually because the array is fluid and will change both in its values and length after some time.

This is my HTML:

```
<mat-form-field style="text-align: center;"
[ngClass]="{'hideTitle': submitted && f4.houseNumber.errors?.required && f4.aptNumber.errors?.required}">
    <input matInput 
      [matDatepicker]="picker" 
      placeholder="Desired Delivery Date" 
      [matDatepickerFilter]="myFilter"
      formControlName="deliveryDate" 
      style="font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif; color:white;">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker" 
    style="color:gold;outline:none;"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker touchUi #picker disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

This is my array:

```
this.allDupedDates = [
  new Date('2019-04-30T00:00:00+02:00'),
  new Date('2019-04-28T00:00:00+02:00'),
  new Date('2019-05-21T00:00:00+02:00'),
  new Date('2019-05-23T00:00:00+02:00')
]
```

And this is the code:

```
myFilter = (d: Date): boolean => {
 const time = d.getTime();
 const day = d.getDay();
for (let i = 0; i < this.allDupedDates.length; i++) {
  var date = this.allDupedDates[i].getTime();
  return time !== date
}
return day !== 6;
}
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `d` and all the `allDupDates` have had their hours/minutes/seconds/millis set to 0 ?  Also, could any allDupDates be Saturday ?  Better to have `if (day === 6) {return false;}` before the `for`.

Comment: hours/minutes/seconds/millis are set to 0.  If i return false than every date becomes invalid.

Comment: The timezone means the hour is not zero - eg, `(new Date('2019-05-23T00:00:00+02:00').getTime() / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24` returns 22 .  So best to compare that the time part matches what your are being given as 'd' - eg, display`time % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)` and `date % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)` to ensure the comparison.    When returning false, did you switch the comparison (note that I had `=== 6`, not the original `!== 6`  ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Filter code you need:**

```
myFilter = (d: Date): boolean => {
  const day = d.getDay();
  const blockedDates = this.allDupedDates.map(d => d.valueOf());
  return (!blockedDates.includes(d.valueOf())) && day !== 6;
}
```

- Date objects can be easily compared with each other using the valueOf() method which returns their milliseconds since epoch.

**Important tips to note:**

- Make sure the date objects you create in dupedDates are created in the same time zone where the filter is being executed. This ensures the timezones are the same and there will no timezone offset issues. **Eg: 30th April 2019 00:00:00 changing to 29th April 2019 23:30:00.**
- The argument d:Date in the filter function will always be supplied with a date representing midnight in the client location's timezone. Eg: If the app is accessed from India: d will contain **29th April 2019 00:00:00 +05:30, 30th April 2019 00:00:00 +05:30, so on...**

StackBlitz Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datepicker-filter-so?file=app%2Fdatepicker-filter-example.ts

Comment: Thank you so much! It is 4 am and im still trying to solve this.. you helped a lot!

Comment: Good answer :)   Note that although getTime() and valueOf() are basically the same, getTime() is the one that should be used.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf  , and note "This method is usually called internally by JavaScript and not explicitly in code."

Comment: @JulianDave Glad to help!! If this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. Thanks!